# magento add extra product to cart automatically

Tags: php, magento

I want to add products automatically to my magento cart.

The situation is I have product Y and it needs extra components to be assembled, so I want that the assembly parts to be added automatically to the cart when product Y is added.

I have googled a lot and could only find extensions for promotion product and free gifts but I need a solution which just adds the product to the cart and that it adds in the same quantity of product Y.

Are there extensions which I can use or how can I alter my code to get my desired behaviour?

Comment: Consider using bundle products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that kind of extension or make you own with a listener on the `sales_quote_item_set_product` event to check if the product added is yours and need a new product to be added.
I had a similar request that was abandonned as it is illegal in France (and in most of the part of Europe) to sell a product linked to another and that was not requested. Moreover, the customer can already have this second product and do not want it. We added a popup that said which products can be needed with this one. This second part is just an advice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you looking programming solutions:

1. Write Custom module that observe event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`.
2. In your observer, add products by following code.

The code is:

```
 $prouctToAdd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('product_id ');
 $qty = 'currently_added_produt'

 $cart =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
 $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty'=>$qty)); 
 $cart->save();
```